# Lazy Stochastic Gradient Descent: Multiplicative vs Additive

Tags: algorithms, optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am reading Bob Carpenter's note at http://lingpipe.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/lazysgdregression.pdf and William Cohen's note at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/10-605/notes/sgd-notes.pdf.

They described the same technique to lazily decay the regularization component of the weight vector (algorithm 2 in Carpenter's). However, I noticed a small difference in their approaches and wondered if this details mattered.

In Carpenter's, the regularization component is updated following $w_i \leftarrow w_i + \eta\frac{u_i - q}{n}\nabla \text{Err}_R$. The vector $\mathbf{u}$ stores the value of $q$ when $u_i$ was last updated. Initially, $\mathbf{u} \leftarrow \mathbf{0}$ and $q=0$. The counter $q$ is incremented *after* the weight vector has been updated for a particular training sample.

In Cohen's, the regularization component is updated following $w_i \leftarrow w_i \times (1-2\lambda\mu)^{(k-u_i)}$ (by the way, they have different notations for the same thing, both $\lambda$ and $\eta$ refer to the learning rate). The counter $k$ is the same as $q$ in Carpenter's note and incremented *before* any update to the weight vector. And $\mu$ is the regularization factor.

I have two questions:

1. Why is Carpenter's adding the regularization component and Cohen's multiplying?
2. When the first training sample comes in, Carpenter's version essentially ignores the regularization because $u_i - q = 0$. However, Cohen's version does decay the current weight value by a factor of $1-2\lambda\mu$. Does this make any difference?